# Pandas replacing some blank rows in column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter a column for only blank rows and then only where another column has a certain value so I can extract first two words from that column and assign it to the blank rows.

My code is:

```
df.loc[(df['ColA'].isnull()) & (df['ColB'].str.contains('fmv')), 'ColA'] = 
      df['ColB'].str.split()[:2]
```

This gets executed without any errors but when I check `df['ColA'].isnull().sum()` it shows the same number as before.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: [numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

Comment: Try `df['ColA'] = np.where(df['ColA'].isnull() & df['ColB'].str.contains('fmv'), df['ColB'].str.split()[:2], df['ColA'])` but would prefer to see some data to determine if there are better solutions available.

Comment: @cs95 gives me an error: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1156,) (2,) (1156,)

Comment: I solved it.. Needed to modify the right side to df['ColB'].str.split().str[:2]

Answer (score 1):

Your code works well except you have a typo:

```
df.loc[(df['ColA'].isnull()) & (df['ColB'].str.contains('fmv')), 'ColA'] = \
    df['ColB'].str.split().str[:2]  # you need str[:2] and not only [:2]
```

But why doesn't it work? Probably because your conditions are not filled together. I mean you can have null values but for these rows there is no 'fmv' strings.

Example:

```
>>> df
  ColA         ColB
0  NaN  abc def ghi  # <- ColA is null but ColB does not contains fmv
1  abc  abc def fmv  # <- ColB contains fmv but ColA is not null
2  NaN  abc def ghi  # <- ColA is null but ColB does not contains fmv
```

So the code above works but nothing change. Check this with:

```
>>> sum(df['ColA'].isnull() & df['ColB'].str.contains('fmv')
0
```

If the result is 0 neither `df['ColA'].isnull()` nor `df['ColB'].str.contains('fmv')` match together.